What does this verse with which John begins his second epistle mean: “The elder to the elect lady and her children, whom I love in truth”
Jan 4, 2022 — John begins his second epistle with these words: “The elder to the elect lady and her children, whom I love in truth”

I have edited your question, if you do not agree with my edit you are free to change it again. Welcome to BH. The meaning of this verse has been asked before. eg:  "Who is the "elect lady" of Second John?." Do read the tour [below, left] to help you see how this site works.

Does this answer your question? Who is the "elect lady" of Second John?

Let's break it down:
The elder
We assume from the introduction that the writer is the Apostle John.

(1 a.) (1) The elder.—The word is used with reference to age in
1Timothy 5:2; 1Peter 5:5; with reference to office, Acts 11:30; Acts
14:23; Acts 15:4; Acts 15:6; Acts 15:23; Acts 16:4; Acts 20:17;
1Timothy 5:1; 1Timothy 5:17; 1Timothy 5:19; Titus 1:5; James 5:14;
1Peter 5:1. - Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers

The Apostle's use of "the elder" in 2 John likely reflects his advanced age and unique status. He likely used this indicating his esteemed position as a revered teacher and probably the last surviving Apostle, rather than simply identifying himself as one among many presbyters.[a]
to the elect lady and her children
It is either unto the elect Lady or possibly, unto the elect Kyria.

but the other is better, as leaving open the question, which cannot be
determined with any approach to certainty, whether the letter is
addressed to an individual or to a community. There is no article in
the Greek, so that ‘to an elect lady’ is a possible translation. - Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges


It is either a description of the Church, and the τέκνα are her     individual members. Displaying the Church as a mother, and of her members as her children. - Meyer's NT Commentary
Or the elect Kyria. He addresses her as one chosen of God to salvation and her children - The word here rendered "children" (τέκνοις teknois) would include in itself both sons and daughters, but since the apostle immediately uses a masculine pronoun, τοις tois it would seem more probable that sons only were intended. At all events, the use of such a pronoun proves that some at least of her children were sons. - Barnes' Notes

The Pulpit Commentary notes that it is better to render it as "lady" as

We commit ourselves to nothing that is disputable if we render κυρία
"lady;" whereas if we render it "Kyria" it is open to any one to
object that perhaps the lady's name was not Kyria, and that perhaps
she is not an individual at all, but a Church.

I love in the truth

Or rather (as αληθεια is without the article) in truth. The meaning
is, whom I love with unfeigned and holy love. - Benson Commentary


(Ebrard: “I love thee with that love which is a love in truth;”
similarly Lücke: “it is the real Christian love that is meant,” and
Braune). - Meyer's NT Commentary


+1--a good breakdown indeed. Although I do find myself wanting a definite answer - lady or church?

@DanFefferman I wish I had the answer! It's likely better to translate it 'lady' but I have no better answer than the scholars as to whether 'lady' refers to an individual woman or the church.

The syntactic constructions in 2 John 1:1 and 3 John 1:1 are structurally similar, as both begin with "Ὁ πρεσβύτερος" (the elder), followed by a greeting directed to a specific recipient. However, a key difference suggests that κυρίᾳ refers to a female individual, while Γαΐῳ refers to a male.
Syntactic Analysis

2 John 1:1

Ὁ πρεσβύτερος ἐκλεκτῇ κυρίᾳ

ἐκλεκτῇ: Feminine singular dative adjective, meaning "elect" or "chosen."
κυρίᾳ: Feminine singular dative noun, which can mean "lady" or function as a proper name.




3 John 1:1

Ὁ πρεσβύτερος Γαΐῳ τῷ ἀγαπητῷ

Γαΐῳ: Masculine singular dative noun, a proper name (Gaius).
τῷ ἀγαπητῷ: Article + masculine singular dative adjective, meaning "beloved."





Differences and Supporting Arguments

Grammatical Agreement

In 2 John 1:1, the adjective ἐκλεκτῇ agrees in gender with the noun κυρίᾳ (both feminine in dative case).
In 3 John 1:1, the masculine noun Γαΐῳ agrees with the masculine adjective ἀγαπητῷ.

This agreement confirms that κυρίᾳ is feminine, while Γαΐῳ is masculine.

The Use of "κυρίᾳ"

The word κυρίᾳ is widely recognized as feminine, used either as a common noun meaning "lady" or as a feminine proper name.
In the context of 2 John, the dative form κυρίᾳ is modified by ἐκλεκτῇ, which describes a personal quality, strengthening the case for it referring to a specific woman, not a metaphorical entity.


Semantic Parallel

In 3 John 1:1, the elder addresses a specific male individual, Γαΐῳ, and adds the descriptor τῷ ἀγαπητῷ ("the beloved").
Similarly, in 2 John 1:1, the elder addresses a specific person, κυρίᾳ, and qualifies her as ἐκλεκτῇ ("the elect"). This parallel structure indicates a personal salutation.


Contextual Implications

The reference to "her children" later in 2 John (verse 1:1b) supports the idea of an actual woman as the recipient. While some interpret κυρίᾳ metaphorically (e.g., as a church), the grammatical evidence leans strongly toward a literal female individual.



Conclusion
The phrase ἐκλεκτῇ κυρίᾳ in 2 John 1:1 clearly refers to a female person due to the grammatical agreement between the feminine adjective ἐκλεκτῇ and the feminine noun κυρίᾳ. In contrast, Γαΐῳ in 3 John 1:1 is masculine. The consistent use of the feminine dative for κυρίᾳ strongly suggests it refers to a woman, either as a title of honor ("Elect Lady") or as a feminine proper name.
